# EJSONPARSE error with npm when trying to install a package

Tags: json, npm, npm-install

When I try to install an npm package after running npm init, I am am met with this response.

```
C:\Users\User\My Documents\brackets\2007webpackes6>npm install --save-dev babel-core
npm WARN package.json 2007webpackes6@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json 2007webpackes6@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json 2007webpackes6@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "babel-core"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! file C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\babel-runtime\6.9.2\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\babel-runtime\6.9.2\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\My Documents\brackets\2007webpackes6\npm-debug.log
```

The error report is telling that there is no data in the "package.json" but it's there when I open the file.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "2007webpackes6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just today. I used the git bash. When I tried it with the windows cmd it worked just fine. 
Now this doesn't tell you why the error is occurring but maybe it will get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to install Cordova, try "npm cache clean"..